# Mimicking compile time interfaces in python

Tags: python, java, interface, protocols, mypy

## Summary

This question first uses Java examples to demonstrate what I am trying to achieve, then shows Python equivalents where I attempt to replicate the compile time behavior, but fail.

## Java

In Java, the compiler immediately throws an error if derived classes don't implement functionality required by abstract base classes or interfaces:

### Using Abstract Base Class

```java
abstract class A {
  abstract int f();
}

class B extends A {
/*
  int f(){
    return 0;
  }  
*/
}

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("done");
  }
}
```

Comment out function `f` in class `B` definition:

- `javac test.java` fails with `B is not abstract and does not override abstract method`

Uncomment function `f` in class `B` definition:

- `javac test.java` succeeds

### Using Interface

```java
interface A {
  int f();
}

class B implements A {
/*
  public int f() {
    return 0;
  } 
*/
}

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("done");
  }
}
```

Comment out function `f` in class `B` definition:

- `javac test.java` fails with `B is not abstract and does not override abstract method`

Uncomment function `f` in class `B` definition:

- `javac test.java` succeeds

## Python

Interfaces don't really exist in python, but they are supposed to be closely approximated by the `Protocol` class in the `typing` module. Abstract base classes do exist in the `abc` module.

What I've found, however, is that the python interpreter never complains about unimplemented behavior **unless** derived class `B` is instantiated.

### Using Abstract Base Class

```py
from abc import abstractmethod, ABC


class A(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def f(self) -> int: ...

class B(A): ...

if __name__== "__main__":
    #b = B()
    print("done")
```

The following occurs if I comment out line 10:

```
- `python test.py` succeeds
- `mypy --strict test.py` succeeds
```

And the following occurs if I uncomment line 10

```
- `python test.py` fails with `TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class B with abstract method f`
- `mypy --strict test.py` fails with `Cannot instantiate abstract class "B" with abstract attribute "f"`
```

### Using Protocol

```py
from typing import Protocol
from abc import abstractmethod

class A(Protocol):
    @abstractmethod
    def f(self) -> int: ...

class B(A): ...

if __name__=="__main__":
  b = B()
  print("done")
```

Just like with an abstract base class, the following occurs if I comment out line 10:

```
- `python test.py` succeeds
- `mypy --strict test.py` succeeds
```

And the following occurs if I uncomment line 10

```
- `python test.py` fails with `TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class B with abstract method f`
- `mypy --strict test.py` fails with `Cannot instantiate abstract class "B" with abstract attribute "f"`
```

## Question

I am not always instantiating the necessary classes which implement protocols or extend abc's in python. So I would like to mimic "compile" time interfaces in python, preferrably with `mypy`.

Is this possible? If not, why not?

Comment: Is there anything I can do to make this question more clear?

Comment: Can be possible at run time to raise an error if a class derived by an abstract class does not implement all the abstract methods (also if it is not instantiated). But i don't think it can be done with mypy.

Comment: I think the issue is why you want that in the first place. If you're not instantiating the class, then you're probably (mis)using the class as a container for functions. There is no check for the signatures anyway, so use is limited.

Answer (score 2):

I have found a workaround with mypy: the decorator `@final`. Example:

```
from typing import final

class A(ABC):   
    @abstractmethod
    def f(self) -> int: ...    
    @abstractmethod
    def g(self) -> int: ...

@final
class B(A):    
    def f(self) -> int: ...
```

will raise the error: `Mypy: Final class B has abstract attributes "g"`

The only problem is that a final class cannot be subclassed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the crucial difference is that in Java you explictly declare your class as `abstract` or, by omission, concrete. Then it is an error for a non-abstract class to inherit abstract methods from a base without concretely overriding them.

In Python a class implicitly is abstract if it has any abstract methods (whether inherited or defined in that class), and non-abstract if it doesn't. Therefore, it's not an error to define a class that fails to override its inherited abstract methods -- it just means you're defining an abstract derived class.

The `@final` decorator resolves the issue since a final abstract class makes no sense and is rejected. So, it asserts that the class is non-abstract, but as an incidental side-effect of its real purpose.

I don't have a full list of all the things mypy lets you do with a concrete class but not an abstract one, that could be used as a check. If we had such a list then we could exhaustively search for a solution, and if none of them helps then that proves there isn't one! For example I believe `Type[X]` used to be disallowed for abstract X, but I don't think it is any more.

If you don't mind some horrible boilerplate per concrete class, then after each non-final class that you want to assert is concrete, you could write:

```
@final
class concrete_check(B):
    pass
```

mypy will reject this if B is abstract.

I had a thought that it might be possible to do something like:

```
T = TypeVar("T", bound=type)
def concrete(clz: Type[T]):
    @final
    class Foo(But what goes here?):
        pass
    return clz
```

The problem of course is that Python wants you to put `clz` as the base class of `Foo`, or in general a class, and so will not accept `T` there. mypy requires you to supply a compile-time-resolvable type as the base class, so it won't accept a variable `clz`. And of course since Python won't accept `T`, `mypy` rejects it too.

As a last resort you could easily enough write a class decorator that examines all the methods of the class, and raises an exception if any of them is abstract, and then decorate your class with `concrete`. But that's only going to trigger when the decorator is executed at runtime, not at static analysis time.